# AudioKit 4.2 from CocoaPods Issue miss file

Tags: cocoapods, audiokit

Installing AudioKit using CocoaPods gets an issue missing a file. 
On file AKModulatedDelayDSP.hpp ...

```
#import "ModulatedDelay.hpp"
```

'ModulatedDelay.hpp' file not found

Tried several times on different projects getting the same issue. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're importing from AudioKit.  I don't think you'd get this with a vanilla project.  But, if what you're doing requires access to core, then you might not want to use Cocoapods anyway.  If you shared your project I could give you a more complete answer.

Comment: This is the project I'm trying to install: https://github.com/cemolcay/AUSequencer

Comment: The podfile:

target 'AUSequencer' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.2'
  pod 'Audiobus'
end

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look, probably have a fix in 4.2.4 tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: So, actually I took a look at his example and he's doing an "import AudioKit/AudioKit.h" for no reason apparently, try commenting line 12 of AudioEngine.mm.

Comment: That is ... Thanks!!! works removing  "import AudioKit/AudioKit.h" from AudioEngine.h

Comment: Aurelius, by the way... Do know know any other sample code for Link implementation in AudioKit ?

Comment: No, but I talked to Cem and he still has plans to push that example along with more AudioKit integration in the future.

Comment: I'm running into this. I'm compiling the AudioKit framework from source within my app. I'm going to move on to something else for now, but just wanted leave a comment that this may still be an issue. I'm not sure where the best place is to leave "me too" comments like this.

Comment: Yes, same problem here. Building AudioKit from source. Actually, I've been looking at adding parts of AudioKitSynthOne to my project; that's when things went sideways. (I may give it a go using CocoaPods.)

Comment: Quick update: same error using CocoaPods. I'm using "pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.2', pod 'Audiobus', as recommended above. (Pod version came down as 4.3.) I get the error from building `S1DSPKernel+process.mm`.

Comment: UPDATE: Using CocoaPods for AK, then cleaning Derived Data got past the error. Just a **note** that I had to escape the quotes in `Press \"Save\" to save...` equivalent in a few of the languages localization files (in Presets).